# Comparing vectors of different length c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm developing a version of Conway's Game of Life in which a user may input their own rules for cell birth, death, and survival in the format "B##/S##". In order to implement these rules, I use basic string parsing to move the birth (B) rules and survival (S) rules into separate vectors. However, I'm running into trouble forming the survival vector.

The original cell rules are in a vector, and its contents are compared to the cell birth vector. The problem I have is that when a rule string such as "B012345678/S183" is entered, parts of the survival vector are not being added because one vector is longer than the other, causing a comparison of empty values and a segfault.

My question is: is there something I can do to fill those empty values, or is there a way to pass over those empty values?

```
// Extract cell birth rules from rules string
vector<char> cellBirth(vector<char> cellrules) {
int i = 0;
   vector<char> birthrule;
while (cellrules[i] != 'S') {
    birthrule.push_back(cellrules[i]);
    ++i;
}
return birthrule;
}


// Extract cell survival rules
vector<char> cellSurvive(vector<char> cellrules, vector<char> cellbirth) {
vector<char> surviverule;
long size = cellrules.size();
//cout << "Cellrule size: " << size << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (cellrules[i] != cellbirth[i]) {      //Comparison happens here
        surviverule.push_back(cellrules[i]);
    }
}
return surviverule;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cellbirth is always going to be smaller than cellrules, so your approach is wrong.  There are MANY ways to skin this cat, here is one:

```
vector<char> cellSurvive(vector<char> cellrules) {
vector<char> surviverule;
bool pastS = false;
for (int i = 0; i < cellrules.size(); i++) {
  if (pastS)
    surviverule.push_back(cellrules[i]);
  else if (cellrules[i] == 'S')
    pastS = true;
}
return surviverule;
}
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for the help!